# adding triples in 4store

Tags: python, debian, sparql, 4store

here url_add is a link that contains the rdf triples that i want to store in 4store.but if i pass url_add as an argument it generates Relative URIerror .

so what is the way in which i can pass url_add as an argument only.

response = store.add_from_uri('url_add')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_gstudio-0.3.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/testing1.py", line 152, in

```
response = store.add_from_uri('url_add')
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_gstudio-0.3.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/HTTP4Store/HTTP4Store.py", line 74, in add_from_uri

```
r_obj = self.rh.GET(uri, headers=headers)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_gstudio-0.3.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/HTTP4Store/utils.py", line 53, in GET

```
return self._request("%s" % (path), method="GET", headers=headers)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_gstudio-0.3.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/HTTP4Store/utils.py", line 92, in _request

```
resp, content = self.h.request(path, method, headers=headers, body=data)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 1297, in request
    (scheme, authority, request_uri, defrag_uri) = urlnorm(uri)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 204, in urlnorm
    raise RelativeURIError("Only absolute URIs are allowed. uri = %s" % uri)

RelativeURIError: Only absolute URIs are allowed. uri = url_add

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of your URL

It is throwing an exception because you are passing a relative url instead of an absolute (you probably have something like "../../directory/filename.rdf"

If your url is an HTTP url e.g (http://host/filename.rdf) and **dereferenceable** then you can also use the LOAD directive as part of SPARQL update. So that simply means exectuting a SPARQL query (in the same way you execute a SPARQL query using 4store) using the following expression:

```
LOAD <http://host/filename.rdf>
INTO GRAPH <http://optional-name-of-graph>
```

Comment: ok...actually i hav a code named rdf.py that generates rdf code ..what i want to do is to directly move dat file in 4store..